# Ruby Marshal dump format/bad symbol error

Tags: ruby, marshalling

We are using Marshal to dump file after each successful test. We are reading this file while executing the test. This file is used in Cucumber and rspec tests. Cucumber test run okay first time when we run any cucumber test which add data to this dump file. But if we rerun same cucumber test again it throw bad format/bad symbol error.

This problem doesn't happen when we only run rspec tests. 
FYI: This setup is running fine our hudson build server.

Thanks!